# Cleaning up duplicate files in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

There are several duplicate files in my TYPO3 installation. Also some duplicates in sys_file for the same file (different 'uid', same 'identifier' and 'storage').

The reasons the duplicates were created are:

- first of all, this is an older site, so the previous behaviour (before FAL) resulted in duplicates anyway which were then moved to _migrated. (I am not sure if the upgrade wizard at that point did some cleaning up as well.)
- editors just upload things more than once sometimes and lose track of existing files (in spite of file mountpoints used and a sensible directly structure)
- I don't know the exact reason for the duplicates in sys_file (different uid, but same storage and identifier), but they appear to be mostly related to the _migrated files.

What I would now like to do is create a script / extension to clean this up or assist editors to clean it up (e.g. show duplicates).

- files with same content hash (but different filename / path) could be merged which means also merging all references
- duplicates in sys_file should also get merged

I have a rough idea how this could be done but would like to know if there are already tools, experiences or knowledge anyone could share.

Comment: for linux systems there is [`fdupes`](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes). either you could use the output or get the logic and reimplement in PHP for usage with TYPO3 tables.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but take a look at this Extension https://github.com/fabarea/media and its "Find duplicate files" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 2 different things:

1. **Duplicates in sys_file** (database table) where the uid is different but identifier and storage are the same. This is an inconsistency and should not normally happen. It might have occurred due to unproper handling of files or previous bugs. This should be fixed ASAP.
2. Duplicates where the **file content is the same**, but path different. Ideally, this should not happen but it is not so easy to fix: The files may be in different locations in the file system where some editors may have permission to one, but not the other. It makes sense to clean it up, if possible. But this must not always be a problem in itself.

---

For both situations one should be very careful not to make the situation worse. In general, follow these recommendations to prevent problems and inconsistencies with files in TYPO3:

- Ideally use only TYPO3 functionality when handling files, do not just add, rename or remove them directly on the filesystem (unless you know what you are doing). The reason is that there is an entry in the DB sys_file for every file and this should be updated if files are changed. This happens automatically if you use TYPO3 functionality.
- before removing files and / or sys_file entries, check if there are references to this file

### 1a. Check for sys_file duplicates

When doing the database query to retrieve duplicates, one can query for records in sys_file where uid is different, but identifer is the same, but (!):

- make sure you do not only consider identifer, but check for storage as well (identifier, storage should be unique). Even if you have only one storage (fileadmin), an additional system storage (storage=0) may exist for files which are handled by TYPO3 but are not in fileadmin
- remember that DB queries are usually case insensitive

So this does NOT suffice:

```
# not recommended
SELECT identifier,count(*) from sys_file group by identifier having count(*) > 1;
```

Better:

query 1:

```
SELECT storage,MAX(identifier),COUNT(*) 
  FROM sys_file
    GROUP BY md5(identifier),storage 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
  ORDER BY storage,MAX(identifier);
```

Alternative (should work as well, if identifier_hash is correct. Since there are already inconsistencies, it seams a good idea not to just rely on this, but make sure):

query 2:

```
SELECT storage,identifier,count(*) AS c 
  FROM sys_file 
  GROUP BY identifier,storage,identifier_hash 
  HAVING count(*) > 1
  ORDER BY storage,identifier;
```

If query 1 and 2 return different number of results, there are reasons to believe `indentifier_hash` is not always correct and this should be fixed as well.

### 1b. Fix the sys_file duplicates

There is an extension `elementareteilchen/unduplicator`, but please look at my [issue](https://github.com/ElementareTeilchen/unduplicator/issues/2) first and carefully check if this will work on your system:

- https://github.com/ElementareTeilchen/unduplicator

### 2. Fix content duplicates

In the comments, someone suggested https://github.com/fabarea/media.
I do not have any experience with this.

Important is to fix the sys_file duplicates (if there are any) first (or change the DB query so that entries with different uid, but same storage and identifier are not considered).

A possible approach might be:

You can search for content duplicates by searching for entries with different uid but same hash `sys_file.sha1`:

```
SELECT f1.uid,f2.uid,f1.sha1,f2.sha1,f1.storage,f1.identifier,f2.storage,f2.identifier
  FROM sys_file f1 
    INNER JOIN sys_file f2 
      ON f1.sha1=f2.sha1
  WHERE f1.uid != f2.uid
     and BINARY f1.identifier != BINARY f2.identifier;
```

A safe solution which is relatively easy to implement is to only remove the duplicates which have no references. Use TYPO3 functionality to get the references.

Comment: "do not just add, rename or remove them directly on the filesystem" => In my opinion, TYPO3 should be able to handle that. There are so many reasons files are added directly in file system. E.g. when updating an extension (media files located in extensions are also added to sys_file).

Comment: But how should TYPO3 be able to detect if a file has been renamed? In the case of adding and removal, yes that should be possible.

Comment: By saving and comparing a hash of the file contents (it seems like TYPO3 is doing this already, in "sys_file.sha1"), and eventually a second check, e.g. by comparing the first 50 characters of the file contents.